# How to flatten a 2D data into 1D in Alteryx

Tags: alteryx

I am a newbie to Alteryx and trying to solve a rather difficult problem. My data is not only unclean but also extremely entangled (example below):

[image]

I want to transform it to a flattened format which can be used to run aggregation and other sorts of analysis. Following is the output:

[image]

How to go about it?

Comment: Ask the same at community.alteryx.com; you'll probably have a sample workflow within a day.

Comment: Thank you! Question posted: https://community.alteryx.com/t5/Alteryx-Designer-Discussions/How-to-flatten-a-2D-data-into-1D-in-Alteryx/m-p/466694/highlight/false#M92116

Comment: Did the answer in the Alteryx Community help you ? (You should mark it as correct there if it does)

Comment: I didn't get time enough to do the same. Shall try out and write back and do all the needful. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't have Alteryx at hand,

1. Rename last 8 of 9 columns.
   Example:

Column B to

"Company A,2018,Shareholding"

COlumn C to

"Company A, 2018, percentage"

2. Then use a Sample Tool to split your records to two flows, Individuals, Companies (Union them back in the final step), then a Formula Tool to specify each part as "individual promoters" or "Companies" will be handy

Do below for both parts:

3. use a Transpose Tool (choose 8 renamed columns as "data columns", the Formula tool above can be "key columns"), therefore, company, year, shop name are in a horizon place, you get Name/Value pair:

"Individual Promoters","Company A, 2018, Shop1, ShareHolding", 250,000

"Individual Promoters","Company A, 2018, Shop1, Percentage", 0.000273

4. use text to columns, comma as separator, you get 4 columns needed.
5. Use a Formula tool followed by a filter Tool, to split "ShareHolding" and "Percentage" to two flows
6. Use Join (3 join keys: company, year, shopname) to join them back, you now get:

Company A, 2018, Shop1, 250,000,0.000273

7. Use aforementioned Union to combine "individual promoters" and "companies" back to 1 flow.

Done